# C2059: syntax error : 'public' in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I was getting this error which was driving me crazy. I just added a class using Qt Creator but it will not build.

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

class Library
{
public:
    Library();

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // LIBRARY_H
```

The errors are:

```
library.h:12: error: C2059: syntax error : 'public'
library.h:12: error: C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body
library.h:13: error: C2760: syntax error : expected '{' not '}'
library.h:13: error: C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before ';'
library.cpp:4: error: C2535: 'Library::Library(void)' : member function already defined or declared
library.cpp:8: error: C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was Qt Creator added `signal`and `slots` even though I added a C++ class (as opposed to Qt class) and didn't derive it from `QObject`.

The solution is to remove `signal` and `slots`words from the class or derive it from `QObject` and `#include <QObject>`

Comment: Q_OBJECT macro is also needed in class declaration and in case of multiple inheritance - QObject should be the first in that list

Comment: @Shf thanks Q_OBJECT macro is indeed required for `QObject` derived class to work properly (signal and slots) however the compiler error does go away even without it. That said definitely include it to avoid a different set of unexpected errors. I thought I would comment that for the sake of completeness.